Backup (deja-dup) on 20.04 LTS suddenly stopped working after months
A while ago I set up Backup/DejaDup to backup to a local USB hard disk. That's been running happily for a few months but now fails with
InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://

presumably after some update, although I don't see any recent releases for dejadup packages. I also can't find any config file. I did find some "registry settings" in the dconf-editor app, where the local folder is set to /mnt/backup24/deja/howie - a folder that exists, but doesn't have any URL scheme on the front. I didn't set this, the dejadup application did, after I picked a directory in the filepicker. I don't see anything saying invalid:// and also: it's not a relative path!
So what is missing? The Deja Dup version is 40.7 (+ duplicity 0.8.12), which seems kind of old (latest on DD website is 46.x), but isn't that what LTS is supposed to keep up with? The DejaDup website behind app.gnome.org seems to be mostly aimed at people writing DejaDup...
(I actually have another question about how scheduling for it works, so I can schedule different users at different times, but for now, working at all would be nice! :-) )
Edit: after reading the duplicity manual, I tried adding a file:// scheme in dconf-editor. Deja-Dup treated that as an entirely new backup and created a directory in my home directory called file:
Edit 2: DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 showed that it's duplicity complaining.
DUPLICITY: . User error detail: Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 106, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1525, in main
DUPLICITY: .     action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1175, in ProcessCommandLine
DUPLICITY: .     globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 225, in get_backend
DUPLICITY: .     obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 188, in get_backend_object
DUPLICITY: .     if not is_backend_url(url_string):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 172, in is_backend_url
DUPLICITY: .     pu = ParsedUrl(url_string)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 336, in __init__
DUPLICITY: .     raise InvalidBackendURL(u"missing // - relative paths not supported "
DUPLICITY: .  duplicity.errors.InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://
DUPLICITY: . 

DUPLICITY: ERROR 23 InvalidBackendURL
DUPLICITY: . InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://

But /usr/bin/duplicity and /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py both haven't changed since 2020. So it seems as though the join between deja-dup and duplicity is the issue.
CLI restore using the duplicity command line worked fine (using a file:// URL for the archive)

Some troubleshooting steps: Can you browse the backup directory in a file manager? Is the path to the backup directory exactly what you expect it to be? Can you restore a single file of your choice from the backup using duplicity --file-to-restore [the file] [backup location] [place to put it]

You could do an export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 then run deja_dup on the command line like /usr/bin/deja-dup --backup --auto this will output LOADS of debug info which may help you to see what it's doing and in what context it's giving that error. As for scheduling, personally I use crontab running a bash script but I only have a single backup. As far as I know deja-dup does not offer any ability to pass backup config on the command line to do different backups etc.

Deja Dup runs as you, so I have two users (work, and personal) both of whom have run the Backup app to set up their backups. That works, but they both run at the same time which probably shreds the disk a bit more than necessary.
duplicity restore works fine. The directory shows up fine in the file manager.

The deja-dup stores it setup data such that it can be accessed using the dconf-editor. If you haven't got it then do the following: -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install dconf-editor

Start the dconf-editor from a command line dconf-editor
Read and heed the warning message.
Then select the top of the tree on the top line. (Circle with tick in it) then follow the path org gnome deja-dup.
Scroll down to backend. I have it set to local but you probably have it set to remote. If I scroll back up and click on local I see the destination of the backend (what deja-dup calls the storage location). (I have a local file stored in mine. For you select remote. click on that shows where your files are stored.
Note: The above is equivalent to deja-dup->preferences->location which selects between different remote and local locations which you set before selecting the file-path/file.
To get back just go to the top line and click on a higher level of the path.
If you change anything nothing will happen until you assert the apply (only appears if there is something to change) or leave the application. To cancel anything before this click on the circle with three dots left of the apply button.

When Deja-dup works it copy the backend into the {HOME}/.cache/deja-dup/{DEJA_DUP_HASH}/ These are really Duplicity files. There is also a Duplicity log.
It uncompresses them and modifies them. These are text files so you can edit them but be careful not to damage them in any way.

As already stated you can run deja-dup in debug mode using the following: -
DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup | tail -n 200 > /tmp/deja-dup.log

the log file can be used to debug problems.

I hope this is of some help,
Enjoy

Yes, I already mentioned dconf-editor in the question :-) The backend is "local"

But your data is on a USB device? (Not local.) Insert your USB with your data, then run deja-dup. Select  deja-dup->preferences->location. It is a drop down menu. Select the USB device. Now select the folder archive from the next line. Hopefully you will see your archive.

It's an ext4-formatted USB hard disk, mounted in fstab the same as any other disk. Not sure why anything above the device driver would care that it's USB... besides, it has been working for several months!

I did try it on my rig with an ext4 formatted USB drive (but not in fstab) and you still have to select it in deja-dup.
